# Relational Algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I was wondering if I could get some feedback on the relational algebra I have done and any advice on improving it also if you see anything wrong with my SQL could you possibly point it out.

```
SELECT CourseName
FROM Course
WHERE CourseNo = 6;
```

**∏CourseName(σCourseNo=6(Course))**

```
SELECT CU.UnitNo
FROM C.Course, CU CourseUnit
WHERE C.CourseName = CU.CourseNo
AND C.CourseName = 'Research';
```

**∏UnitNo(CourseUnit(σCourseName=’Research’(Course)))**

```
SELECT U.UnitName
FROM S Student, SU StudentUnit, U Unit
WHERE S.StudentNo = SU.StudentNo
AND SU.UnitNo = U.UnitNo
AND S.StudentName = 'John Perry';
```

**∏UnitName(Unit(StudentUnit(σStudentName=’John Perry’(Student))))**

```
SELECT count(S.StudentNo) ResearchStudents
FROM C Course, S Student
WHERE C.CourseNo = S.CourseNo
AND C.CourseName = 'Research';
```

**∏ResearchStudents((C)count(StudentNo)(Student   (σCourseName=’Research’(Course))))**

Answer (score 3):

there is an issue in the from clause, I removed a dot between C.Course

```
SELECT CU.UnitNo
FROM C Course, CU CourseUnit
WHERE C.CourseName = CU.CourseNo
AND C.CourseName = 'Research';
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of Pentium10's comment, you may consider using `JOIN` clauses as opposed to specifying the joins in the `WHERE` clause. In my opinion, it can lead to queries that are easier to follow. So

```
SELECT CU.UnitNo
FROM C Course, CU CourseUnit
WHERE C.CourseName = CU.CourseNo
AND C.CourseName = 'Research';
```

becomes

```
SELECT CU.UnitNo
FROM C Course 
INNER JOIN CU CourseUnit
  ON C.CourseName = CU.CourseNo
WHERE C.CourseName = 'Research';
```

*(side note: the tables have been given aliases but the aliases aren't used - If my memory serves me correctly, SQL Server will complain about this and not execute the query. Not sure about other RDBMS)*

Answer (score 0):

If your syntax is going to be used, I guess the special characters must be exchanged.
(remember the APL keyboards?)

The distance between Course and C is disturbing, in your last example.

Also your Join in the 3rd example is not complete.

I think Query By Example or Linq are more interesting alternatives.